# iOS Navigation Bar Prefers Large Titles Scroll Behaviour

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios11

In iOS 11 the system apps all compress the navigation bar as you scroll down if you enable prefersLargeTitles:

[image]

I can't figure out how to implement this in my own apps though, the bar stays the same by default:

[image]

The only thing I can see is Hide Bars On Swipe, but that hides the whole bar rather than compressing it:

[image]

This is just an empty project created in Xcode 9 beta and with a new storyboard added.

What do I need to do to get the same behaviour as the system apps?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Nope. I saw on the dev forums that multiple radars have been filed for it. Tried in the GM build and it's still the same. In the end I shipped with the content going under the bar. Would really like to get it fixed, but I think it is up to Apple.

Comment: I solved it! Don't set anything in the storyboard, only in code. Worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't set anything regarding Large Titles in Interface Builder / Storyboard, **only in code**. That worked for me.

So in the navigation bar in storyboards, Prefers Large Titles unchecked.

In your view controller:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

Comment: in fact, although this works for the demo, it doesn't work in my app. Obviously there is something more complicated in my setup, but just to advise there is still issues here

Comment: Sure you haven't got some large title setting somewhere in you storyboard?

Comment: my solution was: i need to set the title before the configuration of orefersLargeTitles. i set the title of NavigationItem in Storyboard and now it works perfekt. Before the text was only visible sometimes.

Comment: OK i found additionally out, that self.title has has to be a large count of characters like: self.title = "1234566789012345" If it is short or nil. the text will be cut of like: 123...

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this issue is happening to people for different reasons. None of the above answers helped me, but here's what DID work...

I deconstructed my app to find the cause, which was the view hierarchy in the storyboard. It appears that the `UITableView` view HAS to the the first view in your view controller. I had a `UITableView` with two `UIImageView`s behind it and that's what was causing the issue. Once I removed those `UIImageView`s everything worked correctly.

My fix: I ended up creating a `UIView` in code, adding my two image views to that, THEN adding that `UIView` to the `UITableview.backgroundView`.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you haves sample projects of this working / not working would be great to submit radars with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to target older iOS versions, you’ll also have to wrap the assignment in an availability check:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Hello"
    navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
        ]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

http://iosrevisited.blogspot.in/2017/09/navigation-bar-with-large-titles-and.html